# Tagging with Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, tagging, zend-tag

I'm trying to create the same solutions as below, but using a simple MySQL query (instead of the static version used below where the words/tags are implemented in the code). The name of the MySQL table is "tags" and it has 2 columns "id" & "tag".

Unfortunately I'm a beginner and I wasn't able to solve this. Can someone help me?

```
/* Zend_Tag_Item version*/

$list = new Zend_Tag_ItemList();

$list[] = new Zend_Tag_Item(array('title' => 'Code', 'weight' => 50));
$list[] = new Zend_Tag_Item(array('title' => 'Zend Framework', 'weight' => 1));
$list[] = new Zend_Tag_Item(array('title' => 'PHP', 'weight' => 5));

$list->spreadWeightValues(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));

foreach ($list as $item) {
    $this->view->tagtitle = $item->getTitle();
    $this->view->tagweight = $item->getParam('weightValue');
}


/* Zend_Tag_Cloud version*/

$cloud = new Zend_Tag_Cloud(array(
    'tags' => array(
        array('title' => 'Code', 'weight' => 50,
              'params' => array('url' => '/tag/code')),
        array('title' => 'Zend Framework', 'weight' => 1,
              'params' => array('url' => '/tag/zend-framework')),
        array('title' => 'PHP', 'weight' => 5,
              'params' => array('url' => '/tag/php')),
    )
));

$formdata->pagecontent->tagging = $cloud;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a fetchAll on a DbTable model that implements your MySQL table, and then just loop and add the items, or create the array, for example:

```
$tags = array();
foreach($TagTable->fetchAdd() as $tag) {
     $tags[] = array('title' => $tag['tag'], 'weight' => $tag['weight']);
}

$cloud = new Zend_Tag_Cloud(array('tags' => $tags));
```

Comment: id might not be the right way to implement weight :) better would be do a query with group by tag and count(tag) as weight

Comment: I think it's up to the user, she says she only has id & tag :)